# Delete JavaScript function (declared with let) from chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I defined the following function in a chrome developer console-

```
 let splitNumber=function(num){ 
                  let arr=[];
                  arr=num.toString().split(""); 
                 return arr};
```

Then I tried to delete this function from the console scope using this command -

```
 delete window.splitNumber
  > true
```

Now if I try to use the same variable 'splitNumber' again in the console, I get this error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'splitNumber' has already been declared
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: let doesn't work like var in this case :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A property declared with `let` cannot be deleted

`var`, `let`, and `const` create non-configurable properties which cannot be deleted with the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator. Since you declared the function with `let`, it cannot be deleted.

> Any property declared with `let` or `const` cannot be deleted from the scope within which they were defined.

---

### Why does `delete` return true?

Generally, when a property is non-configurable and cannot be removed, `delete` will return false. So you may be wondering why your `delete` statement returns true.

Well, `delete` returns true if the property does not exist after deletion. This means it will return true either if the delete was successful or if the property never existed in the first place. Unlike `var`, `let` does not create a property on the global object. So `delete window.splitNumber` returns true because `splitNumber` does not exist as a property of the global `window` object.

If you try `delete splitNumber`, it will return `false` indicating that `splitNumber` exists in the global scope and cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware about it. Is there any MDN doc on this?

Comment: Yes, I linked to it in the answer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable using `let` or `const` it wont be added to `window` object.

Your attempt to delete `splitNumber` on `window` object as no effect as it won't exists on `window`.

And the `splitNumber` still exits and it throws error when you try to redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope raises a SyntaxError.

```
if (x) {
  let foo;
  let foo; // SyntaxError thrown.
}
```

In ECMAScript 2015, let bindings are not subject to **Variable Hoisting**, which means that let declarations do not move to the top of the current execution context. Referencing the variable in the block before the initialization results in a ReferenceError (contrary to a variable declared with var, which will just have the undefined value). The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the initialization is processed.

Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more.